# Some HTTPS websites give an error with Midori. Why is this?

Tags: release-freya, midori

I always get the information "SSL handshake failed". What's wrong with Midori or elementary OS website? Other SSL websites are working. Also I can't reach Stack Exchange with Midori

I'm using the new Midori-granite 0.5.11 on elementary-os freya 0.3.1 64bit

Comment: I have same problem, and upgrading `glib-networking` doesn't help. so far, this happen with cloudflare SSL integration.
please tell me if you can open this web using midori https://situsali.com/

Comment: @bluemeda No, sorry, that site also shows "SSL handshake failed"

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem with `glib-networking` related to certain types of SSL certificates. It should be fixed in the next release of elementary OS or if we can determine that it is safe to update this package.

You can reach elementary.io through `http` instead of `https`. Just make sure to remove the "s" from the URL :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this message that the elementary handshake SSL had failed, so I looked for SSL on synaptic and found that ssl-cert needed an upgrade, so I updated it through synaptic. I think that fixed whatever it was asking for.